# How to update "history" by other program

Tags: java, bash

On ubuntu server, I can press up arrow to show the last command line which I used, and we can modify it by `history -r` , for example

```
$>history
... some command here 
...  
$> history -r hello.file
$>cat hello.file
aa
$>history
... some command here
...
aa
```

Of course, when I press up arrow at this time, the command line will give me "aa",

So that, I want some program to help me to do that

my Java sample code is

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("/bin/bash history -r hello.file");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

b.close();
```

but it not work, and java didn't print any exception.

I also test by a simple bash file

my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
history -r hello.file
```

and my test follow is

```
$>history
... some command here
...
$>sh my_bash_file.sh
$>history
... some command here
...
```

it still not working...

How can I update the "history" by a program?

Is it impossible?

Comment: Your question isnt really about java; it is much more about the inner workings of shells and the history command itself. I recommend asking the question on superuser.com; or maybe askubuntu.com.